# Interior of arbitrary products

Tags: general-topology

$\newcommand{\Int}{\operatorname{Int}}$I need help to show that in the product space $R^\omega$, $\Int((0,1)^\omega)=\emptyset$ Hence $$\Int\left(\prod A_
{\alpha}\right)\neq \prod \Int\left( A_
{\alpha}\right)$$ does not hold true, where $\alpha \in A$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $U$ is any non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, it contains some open subset from the standard base of that product, namely a set of the form $\prod_{\alpha} U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha = \mathbb{R}$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$, and equals some non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ otherwise. Such a set can never be a subset of $(0,1)^\omega$.

Comment: so why cant it be s subset of (0,1)? (0,1) is an open set and it's uncountable, isnt it?

Comment: The product set $\prod_\alpha U_\alpha$ cannot be a subset of $(0,1)^\omega$, because the former contains (lots of) points that have one of their coordinates equal to $2$, say, and the latter contains no such points, by definition.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb R^\omega$ has a base of open sets of the form $B=\prod_{n\in\omega}U_n$, where each $U_n$ is open in $\Bbb R$, and $$\operatorname{supp}(B)=\{n\in\omega:U_n\ne\Bbb R\}$$ is finite.$\newcommand{\Int}{\operatorname{Int}}$ Suppose that $\Int\left((0,1)^\omega\right)\ne\varnothing$; then there is a non-empty basic open set $B\subseteq\Int\left((0,1)^\omega\right)$. Let $x\in B$ be arbitrary, fix $m\in\omega\setminus\operatorname{supp}(B)$, and define $y\in\Bbb R^\omega$ by

$$y_k=\begin{cases}
x_k,&\text{if }k\ne m\\
2,&\text{if }k=m\;.
\end{cases}$$

Do you see the contradiction here?

Comment: @ Brian Thank you for your answer. What is supp?

Comment: @Klara: The first displayed line is the definition of $\operatorname{supp}(B)$.

Comment: @ Brian ohh, is this a common name for this set?

Comment: @Klara: No, it was a handy ad hoc notation on my part. I **may** have seen it used elsewhere, but it’s certainly not common.

Comment: @ Brian are you fixing m \in W or n like you wrote it?

Comment: Would the contradiction be that y_k is in R^w but there is open basic set that is a subset of y_k?

Comment: @Klara: Sorry; that was supposed to be an $m$. No, each $y_k$ is simply in $\Bbb R$. But the point $y$ is in $B$ (why?) but not in $\Int\big((0,1)^\omega\big)$ (on account of $y_m$).